# AFP Share Mounting Issues

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, truenas, share, afp

I have setup some AFP shares on our bespoke NAS system running FreeNas but seem to be encountering some issues. All the permissions are the same and the shares setup exactly the same way. I have 4 shares, Data1, Data2, Data3 & Data4.

When connecting to Data3 (for example) by going to `Finder > Go > Connect to Server > afp://my.server/Data3` I enter my password, it hooks up and I can view it's contents, however it appears greyed out. If I do exactly the same process on Data4, it hooks up and I can view it's contents no problem and it is not greyed out and I can add it to my Mac favourites and various things like that. See images below:

When viewing the two shares in finder:

[image: Greyed out AFP Share (Data3)]

When trying to add the two shares to favorites:

[image: Mac Favorites section]

I cannot click on the greyed out share at all (from the favorites section)

Notice there are no considerably different details between Data3 & Data4 -

[image: Data3 & Data4 Comparison]

The real problem I have with this is because anyone who tries to access this has the same problem. I hope someone has some knowledge of why this is happening!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to create entirely new ZFS datasets setup with Windows permissions. I then moved over all the data from our old NAS system, deleted the old dataset and renamed my temporary dataset, resolving the issue - albeit a long winded way!